# FulfillmentCodeHook doesn't have an associated Lambda Function AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am creating a chatbot through Amazon Lex and I have built the bot successfully, however, upon testing it, I get the error:

```
Cannot call FulfillmentCodeHook for Intent OrderBot-xxxx. BotAlias/LocaleId TestBotAlias/en_US doesn't have an associated Lambda Function.
```

I have no clue what the issue is, I've tried keeping lambda function code hooks on and off, nothing has changed, same error, no clue how to fix this.

Comment: Have you found your problem?, the only way i have found how to link a lamnda is when i click in test, then the gear icon, but is pretty odd as that lambda set in there run all the time after an interaction, i thought if i am setting up a fullfilment it will only run on fullfilment

Comment: @Manza I haven't found a solution unfortunately. Yeah it's pretty odd. Did that fix work for you or no?

Comment: I will post an answer as I can add images in there, I think I was able to do what I was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the first part I will look and the only place I can see that you can select a lambda is:

[image]

Havent say that, I feel that it depends what you click in the config, a good way to see if something is missing is at the bottom of the page click in visual builder

[image]

In my example below, the lambda is only executed just before the end of the conversation:

[image]

Hopefully helps

Answer (score 0):

In Deployment in the left menu -> Aliases, select the Alias Name, then select the Language.  This is where you set the Lambda function

[Lex lambda selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOfcB.png)

From Lex documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda-attach.html

Remember that **you can associate each bot alias with at most one Lambda function**. **However, you can define as many functions as you need for your bot within the Lambda code and call these functions in the Lambda handler function**.
For example, while all intents in the same bot alias must call the same Lambda function, you can create a router function that activates a separate function for each intent.

The following is a sample router function that you can use or modify for your application:

```
import os
import json
import boto3

# reuse client connection as global
client = boto3.client('lambda')

def router(event):
    intent_name = event['sessionState']['intent']['name']
    fn_name = os.environ.get(intent_name)
    print(f"Intent: {intent_name} -> Lambda: {fn_name}")
    if (fn_name):
        # invoke lambda and return result
        invoke_response = client.invoke(FunctionName=fn_name, Payload = json.dumps(event))
        print(invoke_response)
        payload = json.load(invoke_response['Payload'])
        return payload
    raise Exception('No environment variable for intent: ' + intent_name)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    response = router(event)
    return response
```

another example of Lambda code hook can be found here (hotel and car booking scenario:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-lex-v2-lambdahook-for-booktripbot/blob/main/lambda_function.py